# Tessellating hexagons over a rectangle

Tags: geometry, hexagonal-tiles, tessellation

I have an infinite grid of hexagons, defined by a cubic (x y z) coordinate system like so:

[image: 3 lines at 120 degree intervals of each other, labeled x, y, and z, and a hexagonal honeycomb pattern using these axes.]

I also have a **viewport** -- a rectangular canvas where I will draw the hexagons.

My issue is this.  Because the grid of hexagons is infinite in all directions, I can't feasibly draw all of them at once.  Therefore, I need to draw all the hexagons that are in the viewport, and ONLY those hexagons.

This image summarizes what I want to do:

[image: Hexagons intersecting inside the rectangular viewport are colored purple and thus rendered, all other hexagons are not rendered and are colored white in the diagram]

In this image, purple-colored hexagons are those I want to render, while white-colored hexagons are those I don't want to render.  The black rectangle is hte viewport -- all the hexagons that intersect with it are to be drawn. **How would I find which hexagons to render (IE their xyz coordinates)?**

Some other info:

- I have a function that can recall a hexagon tile and draw it centered at position(x,y) in the viewport, given its cubic xyz coordinates.  Therefore, all I should need is the xyz coords of each rectangle to draw, and I can draw them.  This might simplify the problem.
- I have formulas to convert from cubic hexagon coordinates to x/y coordinates, and back.  Given the above diagram, r/g/b being the axes for the cubic coords with the image above, x and y being the cartesian coordinates, and s being the length of a hexagon's edge...

  ```
  y = 3/2 * s * b
  b = 2/3 * y / s
  x = sqrt(3) * s * ( b/2 + r)
  x = - sqrt(3) * s * ( b/2 + g )
  r = (sqrt(3)/3 * x - y/3 ) / s
  g = -(sqrt(3)/3 * x + y/3 ) / s
  r + b + g = 0
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's X0, Y0 are coordinates of top left corner, RectWidth is rectangle width, HexWidth = s * Sqrt(3/2) is hexagon width.

Find center of the closest hexagon r0, g0, b0, HX0, HY0. *(Rect corner lies in this hexagon, because hexagons are Voronoy diagram cells)*. Remember horizontal and vertical shift `DX = X0 - HX0, DY = Y0 - HY0`

Draw horizontal row of Ceil(RectWidth/HexWidth) hexagons, incrementing r coordinate, decrementing f, and keeping b the same, `ROWINC=(1,-1,0)`.
**Note** that if `DY > HexWidth/2`, you need extra top row with initial coordinates shifted up `(r0, g0-1, b0+1)`

Shift starting point by `L=(0, 1, -1)` if the `DX < 0`, or by `R=(1, 0, -1)` otherwise. Draw another horizontal row with the same ROWINC

Shift row starting point by alternative way (L after R, R after L). Draw horizontal rows until bottom edge is reached.

Check whether extra row is needed in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the rectangular box in terms of constraints on an axis.

In the diagram, the horizontal lines correspond to `b` and your constraints will be of the form somenumber ≤ b and b ≤ somenumber. For example the rectangle might be in the range 3 ≤ b ≤ 7.

The vertical lines are a little trickier, but they are a “diagonal” that corresponds to `r-g`. Your constraints will be of the form somenumber ≤ r-g and r-g ≤ somenumber. For example it might be the range -4 ≤ r-g ≤ 5.

Now you have two axes with constraints on them, and you can form a loop. The easiest thing will be to have the outer loop use `b`:

```
for (b = 3; b ≤ 7; b++) {
    …
}
```

The inner loop is a little trickier, because that's the diagonal constraint. Since we know r+g+b=0, and we know the value of b from the outer loop, we can rewrite the two-variable constraint on r-g. Express r+g+b=0 as g=0-r-b. Now substitute into r-g and get r-(0-r-b). Simplify r-(0-r-b) to 2*r-b. Instead of -4 ≤ r-g we can say -4 ≤ 2*r-b or -4+b ≤ 2*r or (-4+b)/2 ≤ r. Similarly, we can rearrange r-g ≤ 5 to 2*r-b ≤ 5 to r ≤ (5+b)/2. This gives us our inner loop:

```
for (b = 3; b ≤ 7; b++) {
    for (r = (-4+b)/2; r ≤ (5+b)/2; r++) {
        g = 0-b-r;
        …
    }
}
```

The last bit is to generalize, replacing the constants 3,7,-4,5 with the actual bounds for your rectangle.